# Install docker on Ubuntu 16.04: Unable to locate package docker-ce

Tags: 16.04, docker

I'm installing docker on Ubuntu 16.04. I'm following all the instructions on    https://store.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-server-ubuntu?tab=description

(That instructions are the same on https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntu/ but cleaner).

When I launch the step "2. Get Docker CE", it doesn't find the docker-ce package:

```
me@mypc:~$ sudo apt-get install docker-ce
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package docker-ce
```

I've checked and the repo has been added. I've updated my system, but I don't get the package:

[image: Docker repo added]

Does anyone knows what is wrong here?

Comment: Whats the output of `sudo apt-get update` ?

Comment: It shows a `Get` in all the repos and a `Hit` on the docker one

Comment: Just thinking, may it be that the release i386 is a 32 bits and that's not supported by docker?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not working because the Ubuntu installed is a 32 bits one (as you can see from the repo image, it's the i386 one).

And the installation guide from Docket clearly states:

> **OS requirements**
>
> To install Docker, you need the 64-bit version of one
> of these Ubuntu versions:
>
> - Yakkety 16.10
> - Xenial 16.04 (LTS)
> - Trusty 14.04 (LTS)

I've installed a 64 bits, and all works correctly.

Comment: I have 64 bit and I'm getting the OP's error

Comment: Same as @ahnbizcad, me too, I have the 64 bit version and I get the same error.

Comment: I opened a [similar question on "Linux and Unix"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363048/unable-to-locate-package-docker-ce-on-a-64bit-ubuntu/363058#363058) that maybe can add some advice for some users.